# Назначить через jquery элементу display:flex

Tags: html, jquery, css, google-chrome, safari

Вывожу блок

```js
//block search
    $('.openSearch').click(function () {
        $('.social__hidd').stop().css({
            opacity: 0.0,
            display:'none'
        });
        $('.search').stop().fadeIn(0).css({
            display:'flex'
        }).css({
            // display: '-webkit-flex'
        });
    });

    $('.closeSearch').click(function () {
        $('.social__hidd').stop().css({
            opacity: 1,
            display:'block'
        });
        $('.search').fadeOut(0);

    });
```

```css
.search{
  color: @search;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 20%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: none;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 25;
  
  i{
    color: #fff;
  }



  &__cont{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid @search;
    margin-right: 13px;
  }
  
  &__input{
    width: 207px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border:none;
    height: 30px;
    outline: none;

  }
```

```html
<div class="social">
                <div class="social__hidd">
                    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <i class="fa fa-search openSearch" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="search">
                <div class="search__cont">
                    <input class="search__input main-textLato" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
                    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
                <i class="fa fa-times closeSearch" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
```

По нажатию на кнопку поиск `.openSearch`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скрываются соц сети `.social` и показывается блок `.search`. Блок `.search` организован на flex, поэтому через jq назначаю ему `display:'flex'`. Во всех браузерах, кроме Safari, работает нормально:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в Safari не так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Причину узнал, дело в том что во всех браузерах код jq работает корректно и блоку `.search`  назначается инлайновый стиль `display:flex`, однако в Safari вместо этого назначается инлайновый стиль `display:block`. Почему так происходит понять не могу, что делаю не так? Спасибо!

Comment: У вас windows или linux?

Comment: Я почему спрашиваю. На эти операционные системы есть только древнейшая версия safari. В новых версиях всё будет отображаться нормально

Comment: А какая версия сафари?

Comment: Скорее-всего проблема в версии сафари - не поддерживает flex. либо префиксы не прописаны для flex

Comment: @Yuri у меня винда, и да вы скорее всего правы. Посмотрел версию 5.1.4, где-то  2012 года)))
На мак же последняя 10.0.1.
Как тестировать на винде сайты для последних версий сафари?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov 5.1.4

Comment: @Elena на странице много flex элементов, и они корректно работают, префиксы поставлены, добавил css код в топик.
Спасибо Всем.

Comment: @АлександрАлексеев А к чему тэг [tag:google-chrome]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас есть код для flexbox с вендорными префиксами наверняка для поддержки старых браузеров.

> ```
> display: -webkit-box;
> display: -webkit-flex;
> display: -ms-flexbox;
> ```

Так вот, чтобы это работало сделайте так. Вынесите этот код в класс

```
.flex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
```

Затем из jQuery используйте функцию `toggleClass` с классом `flex`. Либо ещё функции `addClass` и `removeClass`.

Также в jQuery UI функция `toggleClass` расширена и позволяет анимировать включение/отключение класса.

Либо также можно просто перестать поддерживать довольно старые браузеры (если это допустимо для вас). Я считаю, что имею право с нынешним темпом развития называть браузеры 2012 года старыми.

Comment: Спасибо, такое простое решение, не догадался))